# Why is RuntimeException not assignable from Throwable?

Tags: java, instanceof, runtimeexception, throwable

I have a method that (unfortunately) accepts an `Object` instance as its sole parameter. I need to add logic that handles it differently if the `Object` is any type of `Throwable` (that means **all** `Exceptions` - checked or unchecked, as well as **all** `Error`s).

```
public void handle(Object toHandle) {
    if(toHandle.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Throwable.class))
        handleThrowable(toHandle);
}
```

When I invoke this method like so:

```
RuntimeException rte = new RuntimeExceptio("Panic!");
handle(rte);
```

The `isAssignableFrom` check returns false and `handleThrowable` never gets invoked. **Why?**

Instead, I have to use:

```
public void handle(Object toHandle) {
    if(toHanlde instanceof Throwable)
        handleThrowable(toHandle);
}
```

This works, as I expected it to. But still stumped as to why the `isAssignableFrom` isn't working...thanks in advance!

Comment: It is working. You can't assign the super type to the derived type. You really want to know if Throwable is assignable from your type, not the other way around.

Comment: Reverse the `isAssignableFrom`

Comment: That statement will always be false, since RuntimeExceptions (and all Exceptions) are not the same type, or a superclass of Throwable... It's inverted

Comment: Use [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its other way around. here is the java doc of `isAssignableFrom(...)` method

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is
>   either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or 
>   interface represented by the specified Class parameter. 
>   It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false.

So when you do

```
if (toHandle.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Throwable.class))
```

Its actually checking whether `RuntimeException` class object  is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by `Throwable`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [documentation of isAssignableFrom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object
>   is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

So you are actually checking if the class of `toHandle` is a superclass of Throwable. This is not what you want.

You should do it the other way around:

```
if (Throwable.class.isAssignableFrom(toHandle.getClass()))
```

or simply use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

`isAssignableFrom` checks if `this` class is the same as, or a parent of, the argument class.

In your code, you're asking if `toHandle` is the same as or a parent of `Throwable`, which is probably not what you want.